# Using Server side datetime

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm using EF Core 6.

Am I right in thinking that

```
var xx = _dbContext.Captcha
                   .Where(a => a.CreationDate > DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(3))
                   .Count();
```

is going to use the SQL Server's `GetUtcDate()` function rather than sending my client side datetime?

Comment: Where exactly would that use the `GetUtcDate()`?  Instead of `DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(3)`?

Comment: What is the query that is generated when you try it? You can enable debugging via `optionsBuilder.LogTo(Console.WriteLine);`

Answer (score 1):

Sure, some CLR methods can be mapped to SQL functions, UtcNow and AddSeconds will be mapped. You can find more information at MSDN and efcore source code:

- [EF Core](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/7e4815d2b0a686cb51dc0d8c7d969eb0dcef36ac/src/EFCore.SqlServer/Query/Internal/SqlServerDateTimeMethodTranslator.cs#L23C52-L23C71)
- [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/clr-method-to-canonical-function-mapping?redirectedfrom=MSDN)